# Probability of at least two events occurring.

Tags: probability

The proportion of the American adult population that supports candidate Green is p=0.22.  A SRS of 9 adults asks if they agree with the statement “I support candidate Green.”  What is the probability that at least 2 of those surveyed would agree with that statement?

Ok, so far I know that the probability of at least 1 person would be .8931 -edited- was using .88 instead .78- Is that useful in solving for at least two?

Comment: If the question was asked at a meeting of the yellow party, the probability is negligible. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability that at least $2$ support Green is $1$ minus the probability that $0$ people or $1$ person supports Green.

The probability that no one supports Green is $(0.78)^9$.

The probability that **exactly** $1$ person supports Green is $\dbinom{9}{1}(0.22)(0.78)^8$.

We could also do the problem the hard way. The probability that exactly $k$ people support Green is $\dbinom{9}{k}(0.22)^k(0.78)^{9-k}$. Calculate all of these, for $k=2$ to $9$, and add up.

**Remark:** We explain why the probability there is exactly one Green supporter is $9(0.22)(0.78)^8$. Line up the people we are interviewing. The probability that the *first* is a supporter of Green and the rest are not is $(0.22)(0.78)^8$. The probability that the first does not support Green, but the *second* does, and the rest don't is $(0.78)(0.22)(0.78)^7$, which is $(0.22)(0.78)^8$. Similarly, the probability the first two are not supporters, but the *third* is a supporter, and the rest are not is $(0.22)(0.78)^8$. We continue this way through all $9$ people, and end up with $(0.22)(0.78)^8$ added to itself $9$ times, for a total of $(9)(0.22)(0.78)^8$. The point is that there are $9$ different ways in which there is $1$ supporter of Green and $8$ non-supporters.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but when you have 9 over k in the parentheses, what is that?

Comment: It is the binomial coefficient. The symbol $\binom{n}{r}$ represents the number of ways to **choose** $r$ objects from a collection of $n$ objects. In high school, it is sometimes called $C(n,r)$, or $C_r^n$. So $\binom{9}{1}=9$.

Comment: So then the answer would be around 86%, right?                            Just using the shorter way I calculated 1-(P(0)+P(exactly 1)

Comment: I get that $(0.78)^9\approx 0.1068$ and $9(0.22)(0.78)^8\approx 0.2713$. The sum is $\approx 0.378$. Take away from $1$. I get about $0.622$. Haven't figured out where your calculation went astray. Maybe mine also did, but your number is for sure much too large.

Comment: Hey sorry for taking so long, but why did you multiply by 9? Is the coefficient effectively just a fraction? If so, that is where I went wrong.

Comment: @EvanMarsh: I will add an explanation of this special case in a remark at the end, it will take a few minutes.

Comment: Your remark makes sense, but would this way also work?: 1- (P(0)+P(1)). That is what I did, arriving at .8629

Comment: You are calculating what you call $P(1)$ incorrectly. I used exactly the same expression $1-(P(0)+P(1))$ as you did. To repeat, $P(1)=9(0.22)(0.78)^8$.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \mathcal P( \text{at least two agree}) = 1 - \mathcal P(\text{ eight or nine disagree}) =  1- {9 \choose 8}p^8(1-p) - {9 \choose 9} p^9  = 1- p^8(9-8p),\quad  p = .78$$